# Re-licencing for ArcGIS Desktop when no Maintenance purchased?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-license-manager

I have ArcGIS 10.2 in my computer. But recently it suffered OS crash. So obviously I need to re-license the software and I have not subscribed any maintenance package from ESRI. What shall I do?

Comment: This is more a matter of backup restoration than "relicensing".

Comment: Back restoration did not work. Data has been backed up before though.

Comment: Issued license keys are a *part* of the data that constitutes a full backup. Since they're so small, and so critical, you should have them in multiple places, as you have unfortunately discovered.

Answer (score 4):

As long as you purchased a permanent license from Esri or one of its International Distributors, even though you have not purchased Maintenance, it is my understanding that you are entitled to continue to use it in perpetuity.

Consequently, you should contact Esri (or your local distributor if outside the US), explain your circumstances and ask them to re-issue your license.

You should not expect that license to unlock a version of the software later than that which was available at the time your free Maintenance period expired.  In your case it sounds like this was ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.

Comment: I have already contacted the authorized distributor support team. But unlike what you've said they are asking for Maintenance Service Subscription.

Comment: How did you purchase your license?  Which distributor are you dealing with?

Comment: Send an e-mail to Esri corporate Customer Service in Redlands, requesting help in dealing with the distributor. While they have every right to deny maintenance support to someone who neither purchased maintainence nor registered, you might be able to get some intervention.

Answer (score 4):

To complement [@PolyGeo's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/230656/115), I have purchased ArcGIS 10.2 (basic) and never paid maintenance so my personal copy is stuck at that version. As I purchased it I am an "organization of one" on the [MyESRI](https://my.esri.com/welcome) website. This is where you can download the iso image and you can even see the ESU code which would be the code that you type in to authorize it. So technically you don't even need to contact anyone at ESRI. That is assuming you are the person who purchased the original copy and it is linked to your esri global account.

Comment: I did not register in the ESRI website with the GIS software details. I have signed up but there's no software details added in the dashboard.